# 18.04 - screen freezes for 10 seconds after suspension

Tags: 18.04, suspend

Since I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 I've been experiencing this very annoying issue I failed to track down and fix.

It happens after I suspended the computer (the screen went black - either by closing the lid or<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>). When I login back to my user account I can immediately see which application I've been lately using - the state of my work from before the computer was suspended - but it is all frozen for a couple of seconds (~10 sec). What surprises me the most is that I can use mouse and/or keyboard to interact with the applications - I won't see the immediate results of that interaction but after few seconds I can see it worked. Ex. if I have browser tab open with a YouTube video paused I can press <kbd>space</kbd> and I can hear the sound but I still have to wait ~10 seconds for the screen to defreeze.

Anyone with an idea what might cause this issue and/or how to debug it?

Comment: It's a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1532508

Comment: Thanks, @pomsky - I experience this bug as well. But this question is about another scenario - the screen is frozen for 10 seconds *after* log in. So I can type-in my password, click enter and see what's on the screen but it is all frozen for circa 10 seconds before I can start using my computer again.